# Property declared in struct definition of swift is not being identified by the compiler

Tags: swift

I am beginner in Swift, and I was just playing around with structs until I got stuck here. Basically `Student` is a struct that contains `firstName`, `lastName` and `grade` of a student and `Classroom` is a struct that holds the `className` and the array of `students` of type `Student`. But the compiler tells me that `Value of type '[Student]' has no member 'grade`. Am I missing anything here ?

```
struct Student {
    var grade : Int
    var firstName : String
    var lastName : String 
}
struct Classroom {
    var className : String
    var students : [Student]


    func highestGrade() -> Int {
       return students.reduce(0){ result, student in
           return students.grade > result ? students.grade : result

       }
    }
}
```

Comment: **Singular**: `student.grade`. It represents the second parameter in the closure, not the member. Please read the error message and note the square brackets.

Comment: @vadian Thank you so much :)